# Python re: парсер FormData, не могу объединить 3 выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django, formdata

```
def FormDataEncoder(data):
    print('in FormDataEncoder')
    try:
        pattern = {}
        pattern['block']        = re.compile(r'------WebKitFormBoundary')
        pattern['headbody']     = re.compile(r'------WebKitFormBoundary.*\n(?P<header>.*)(?=\n\n)(?P<body>.*)',re.DOTALL)
        pattern['head']         = re.compile(r'([\n ](?P<key>[ a-zA-Z0-9-]*)[ =:]?[" ](?P<value>.+?)[" ;\n])', re.DOTALL)

        index   = []
        res = re.finditer(pattern['block'], data)

        for i in res:
            index.append(i.start())
        count = 0
        file = open('/home/temporary.txt','w')
        while count <= len(index):
            count += 1
            text    = data[index[count-1]:index[count]]
            res = pattern['headbody'].match(text)
            res = res.groups()
            file.write(text)
            #print ('len:'+str(len(res)))
            file.close()
            res2= re.finditer(pattern['head'], res[:-1])

            for i in res2:
                print('i='+str(i))

            print('content:'+str(res['body']))
    except:
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

Лог

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybvYPNihBh5rAEBOJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"

null
------WebKitFormBoundarybvYPNihBh5rAEBOJ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo0"; filename="maksim-grek.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

\FF\D8\FF\E0\00JFIF\00\00\00d\00d\00\00\FF\EC\00Ducky\00\00\00\00\00<\00\00\FF\E1   http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/\00<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 4.2.2-c063 53.352624, 2008/07/30-18:12:18        ">
 <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
    xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/"
   xmp:CreatorTool="Adobe Photoshop CS4 Windows"
```

Первое - функция для парсинга запроса, второе - тело запроса. Уже неделю не могу добить до конца это дело. На [сайте](http://pythex.org/) все работает нормально в 3 этапа. Первый этап - перебор файла и поиск блоков с атрибутами запроса и значением, второй - разбиваю блок на 2 части: в одной атрибуты, во второй значение, которое передается в запросе. Последний этап - разделяю первую часть в виде key:value. Но только не работает оно у меня в реальности даже частями. Написать одно выражение для целого файла у меня так и получилось. Подключать модуль cgi я пробовал сегодня, но объект, который он возвращает пустой. В данном случае я хочу отправить ajax-запрос с полями и файлами (кроме того, файлы засунуть в массив у меня так и не получилось, потому весь запрос выглядит как-то так: var1,var2,photo0,photo1,..,photoN). Но все это работает через tastypie, потому сейчас эту функцию я пишу для десериализатора. Помогите, пожалуйста, а то мне уже просто обидно, что неделя прошла, а результат не то что 0, а None :)

P.S. Первый шаблон работает, второй пустой, к третьему не добрался

Comment: «Подключать модуль cgi я пробовал сегодня, но объект, который он возвращает пустой.» — ну так, наверно, стоит разобраться, почему пустой, прежде чем писать свои велосипеды, не?

Comment: И, кстати, django ведь должна сама всё это парсить; вы по каким-то причинам не можете использовать `request.POST` и `request.FILES` или зачем вам это всё?

Comment: Для того чтобы получить к ним доступ, мне нужно сделать десириализацию данных в tastypie, потому что он по-нормальному принимает только json, а multipart/form-data я могу получить только как бинарный файл. Было бы все так просто, то, могу предположить, что пост я здесь новый не оставлял бы

Comment: А cgi все таки работал, но результат выдавал крякозабрами, где с кодировкой я не разобрался

Comment: `dict(request.POST)` разве не даст что-нибудь json-совместимое? Вообще, мне кажется, лучше создаёте отдельный вопрос в нём расскажите, что вы вообще хотите от django и от tastypie, а то пока мало что понятно)

Comment: Суть в том, что в новых версиях tastypie не доходит до функции hydrate, если пришел не json, а что то другое и в результате он выкидает 400 ошибку. Чтобы это устранить, нужно написать десириализатор, но запара вся в том, что он не принимает request, а только content и недокументированные опции. Content приходит как строка и ее нужно переделать в что-то понятное